# How to replace div's id with a variable?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#divsT > div').hide(); //works
$('#divsT > div').eq(xdiv).show();  //works
```

I need to replace `#divsT` with a variable, but something is wrong here:

```
var a = $(this).parent().attr('id');  //result: xdivsT
var b = a.replace("x", "");  // result: divsT
var c = $('#' + b);  // should be #divsT
c > div.hide();  // doesn't work
c > div.eq(xdiv).show();  // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simply suggest you to use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(c).find('> div').hide(); 
$(c).find('> div').eq(xdiv).show();
```

Comment: Satpal, is there a way to avoid `c` object. Something like: `$('#' + b) > div.hide();`

Comment: @bonaca, You can use `$('#' + b + ' > div').hide();` Plain string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

`c` is the variable holding the jQuery object, so you need to use one of these contextual selectors:

```
$('> div', c).hide(); 
$('> div', c).eq(xdiv).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
var a = $(this).parent().attr('id');  //result: xdivsT
var b = a.replace("x", "");  // result: divsT
var c = '#' + b;  // should be #divsT
$('+c+' > div).hide();  // doesn't work
$('+c+' > div).eq(xdiv).show();
```